# Java stuck, trying to create card game

Tags: java, swing, jframe, instance

My assignment is to try and create a card game and I'm stuck at the point where I am trying to display the cards in a jframe. I have a Displayable instance and a Displayble hand deck and card which implements this. I'm stuck at what to put inside the display method that they have to override and also what I should put in the jframe class/jpanel. Any help is much appreciated thanks a lot.

```
public interface Displayable {
    public void display(Graphics g, int x, int y);
}
```

Example of one of the displayable classes.

```
public class DisplayableCard extends Card implements Displayable {
   Graphics g;
   String filename = "\\images\\classic-cards\\7.png";
   Image image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename)).getImage();

   @Override
   public void display(Graphics G, int x,int y)
   {

   }
}
```

We got given this code to use and told to- "Test your new classes by creating a simple subclass of JFrame, which contains an instance of CardGamePanel.  Simply construct and add an appropriate Displayable object to the CardGamePanel instance to test each Displayable"

```
public class CardGamePanel extends JPanel{
    private Displayable theItem;
    private int x, y;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (theItem != null)
        {
            theItem.display(g, x, y);
        }
    }

    public void setItem(Displayable item, int x, int y) {
       theItem = item;
       this.x = x;
       this.y = x;
    }

}
```

So I tried this:

```
public class simple extends JFrame
{
   CardGamePanel c = new CardGamePanel();      
   Displayable d;
   DisplayableDeck d1 = new DisplayableDeck();
}

public class mainclass {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {   
        DisplayableDeck d1 = new DisplayableDeck();
        simple s1 = new simple();
        s1.c.setItem(d1, 50, 50); // like this?
    }
}
```

Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: You need to give your `simple` object some properties (using `setItem`), and call the `display` method. Can you show those pieces of code?

Comment: I've edited it but the jframe isn't even popping up

Comment: simple.setVisible(true)??

Comment: `We got given this code to use` - well tell your teacher that the code example does NOT follow Swing standards. Custom painting is done in the paintComponent() method, not the paint method. Tell your teacher to read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the proper way to do this.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this program

```
public class HighLow {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  System.out.println("This program lets you play the simple card game,");
  System.out.println("HighLow.  A card is dealt from a deck of cards.");
  System.out.println("You have to predict whether the next card will be");
  System.out.println("higher or lower.  Your score in the game is the");
  System.out.println("number of correct predictions you make before");
  System.out.println("you guess wrong.");
  System.out.println();

  int gamesPlayed = 0;     // Number of games user has played.
  int sumOfScores = 0;     // The sum of all the scores from 
                           //      all the games played.
  double averageScore;     // Average score, computed by dividing
                           //      sumOfScores by gamesPlayed.
  boolean playAgain;       // Record user's response when user is 
                           //   asked whether he wants to play 
                           //   another game.

  do {
     int scoreThisGame;        // Score for one game.
     scoreThisGame = play();   // Play the game and get the score.
     sumOfScores += scoreThisGame;
     gamesPlayed++;
     TextIO.put("Play again? ");
     playAgain = TextIO.getlnBoolean();
  } while (playAgain);

  averageScore = ((double)sumOfScores) / gamesPlayed;

  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("You played " + gamesPlayed + " games.");
  System.out.printf("Your average score was %1.3f.\n", averageScore);

}  // end main()


/**
 * Lets the user play one game of HighLow, and returns the
 * user's score on that game.  The score is the number of
 * correct guesses that the user makes.
 */
private static int play() {

  Deck deck = new Deck();  // Get a new deck of cards, and 
                           //   store a reference to it in 
                           //   the variable, deck.

  Card currentCard;  // The current card, which the user sees.

  Card nextCard;   // The next card in the deck.  The user tries
                   //    to predict whether this is higher or lower
                   //    than the current card.

  int correctGuesses ;  // The number of correct predictions the
                        //   user has made.  At the end of the game,
                        //   this will be the user's score.

  char guess;   // The user's guess.  'H' if the user predicts that
                //   the next card will be higher, 'L' if the user
                //   predicts that it will be lower.

  deck.shuffle();  // Shuffle the deck into a random order before
                   //    starting the game.

  correctGuesses = 0;
  currentCard = deck.dealCard();
  TextIO.putln("The first card is the " + currentCard);

  while (true) {  // Loop ends when user's prediction is wrong.

     /* Get the user's prediction, 'H' or 'L' (or 'h' or 'l'). */

     TextIO.put("Will the next card be higher (H) or lower (L)?  ");
     do {
         guess = TextIO.getlnChar();
         guess = Character.toUpperCase(guess);
         if (guess != 'H' && guess != 'L') 
            TextIO.put("Please respond with H or L:  ");
     } while (guess != 'H' && guess != 'L');

     /* Get the next card and show it to the user. */

     nextCard = deck.dealCard();
     TextIO.putln("The next card is " + nextCard);

     /* Check the user's prediction. */

     if (nextCard.getValue() == currentCard.getValue()) {
        TextIO.putln("The value is the same as the previous card.");
        TextIO.putln("You lose on ties.  Sorry!");
        break;  // End the game.
     }
     else if (nextCard.getValue() > currentCard.getValue()) {
        if (guess == 'H') {
            TextIO.putln("Your prediction was correct.");
            correctGuesses++;
        }
        else {
            TextIO.putln("Your prediction was incorrect.");
            break;  // End the game.
        }
     }
     else {  // nextCard is lower
        if (guess == 'L') {
            TextIO.putln("Your prediction was correct.");
            correctGuesses++;
        }
        else {
            TextIO.putln("Your prediction was incorrect.");
            break;  // End the game.
        }
     }

     /* To set up for the next iteration of the loop, the nextCard
        becomes the currentCard, since the currentCard has to be
        the card that the user sees, and the nextCard will be
        set to the next card in the deck after the user makes
        his prediction.  */

     currentCard = nextCard;
     TextIO.putln();
     TextIO.putln("The card is " + currentCard);

  } // end of while loop

  TextIO.putln();
  TextIO.putln("The game is over.");
  TextIO.putln("You made " + correctGuesses 
                                       + " correct predictions.");
  TextIO.putln();

  return correctGuesses;

  }  // end play()

} // end class
```

You can try out the game in this applet, which simulates the program:

Comment: Thanks, the main issue currently is displaying the cards in the jframe